# C# Entity Framework and Linq - Insert into database using entity model

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, import-from-excel

I am trying to create a program to export excel content/data to a database created in SQL Server 2014. I already have the data (variables) I want to insert into database. Now i am having some problems on the database diagram, in other words how should I build it, and how can I insert those values on it.

This is suppose to be a school schedule to get some querys to other program (independent of this one), so this program is just for the database management.

Now I only have one table for tests, but I know i need to do relations between them.

Original Table (Fields):

- (PK) Id
- StartTime
- EndTime
- Teacher
- Class
- Room
- Subject
- DayWeek

So now I want to create independent tables, which in my head would be:

- Rooms (Id, Room)
- Classes (Id, Class)
- Teachers (Id, Teacher)
- Subjects (Id, Subject)

So the original fields would be replaced by those tables in a one to many relationship if I am not wrong.

So the question is, I don't know how to insert with the relationship, because if there is already one Room/Teacher/Subject/Class with the same name as my variable, I will not insert into the respective table.

May some one help this newbie ^^?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

**Edit**:

Thanks for your answer, but I guess that isn't my problem.
So my database would be like this (any suggestion is welcome to improve the database structure):

Tables (and Fields):

- Schedule (Id (**PK**), StartTime, EndTime, DayWeek, RoomId (**FK**), ClassId (**FK**), SubjectId (**FK**), TeacherId (**FK**))
- Rooms (RoomId (**PK**), RoomName)
- Classes (ClassId (**PK**), ClassName)
- Subjects (SubjectId (**PK**), SubjectName)
- Teachers (TeacherId (**PK**), TeacherName)

So the table **Schedule** have many relationships to different tables (One to Many, if i am not wrong).

Being more specific, the whole database is empty, with those tables and relationships created.

I am filling those tables with data from some excel files, I already read them and got them to variables, in concrete i got these values to variables, from a excel: **StartTime, EndTime, DayWeek, Room, Class, Subject, Teacher**.

My problem is I want to insert these values into the table **Schedule** since it will be the table that i want to get information, but for that I need to also insert data to the "foreign tables". So can you try to help me?

In my way of thinking since I don't have much SQL knowledge I would "ask"/select the Id of every Foreign table record (e.g.: I would get the id of the room/teacher/subject/class (variable got by excel) in the respective foreign table. If exist I would get the id and then i already have the id to insert into schedule table, else I would insert into Foreign table that field and get the id to the schedule table), is this way of thinking right, or there is a easiest way?

This database will only be written once per yer, since I will insert all the teachers schedules into it.

Comment: your database is blank or do you plan to repeat the import again and again?

Comment: This database will only be written once per yer, since I will insert all the teachers schedules into it.

Comment: Being a beginner is OK, but this is basic stuff you should pick up from tutorials. It's far too broad to cover here. It's my impression you didn't even cover the basics of mapping and navigation properties in EF yet. Again, that's OK, but nobody is going to rewrite a tutorial here.

Comment: My problems isnt the EF structure itself cause I already edited some projects, I understand the concept, i know how to do it cause I already have a sample without relation tables, the problem is how to do it correctly.

Comment: I can only judge that by seeing code.

Comment: What's the best solution to show code (more than usual)?

Answer (score 0):

The original fields would be replaced by the Id of order table (foreign key).
If you wanna insert into origin table, your must have data in foreign table, you must have room,teacher, class, ...ect. 
And the code will look like this, take example:

```
context.Fields.Add(new Field { StartTime = ...,......TeacherId = 5,ClassId =6,...ect});


Original Table (Fields):
(PK) Id
StartTime
EndTime
TeacherId
ClassId
RoomId
SubjectId
DayWeek
```